# How to use context without using application name?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, application-name

Previously, I used an `AppController` class extends from Application and in Manifest, that is added.  Now, I prepare a `signupModel` class. In this class, I need `LayoutInflater` because of context. But when debugging, context has `AppController`. However, I want context is not include `AppController`?

```
public class SignUpModel {
Context context ;
EditText signup_email;

public SignUpModel(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sign_up,null);
    signup_email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
}

public String getEmail() {
    return signup_email.getText().toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, using the **static class LayoutInflater** eliminating the need for context and system service

```
public SignUpModel(){
        View view = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sign_up,null);
        signup_email = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
    }
```

Comment: it doesnot work. Still, i cannot get signup_email.getText().toString()

Comment: what does signup_email.getText().toString() return